# Contact form 7 on_sent_ok doesn't seem to always trigger my js function?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, contact-form-7

I must redirect a CF7 form if a certain variable has a specific value.  This variable has a value "free" if a valid code is used and nonfree by default and invalid code.

I wrote a simple js function:

```
function page_redirect(){
 if (document.getElementById("RasAzT").value != "nonfree") {
pspurl = "/do-some-calculation-and-redirect.php";
  window.location = pspurl;
            } else {
                return true;
            }
}
}
```

and I have

on_sent_ok:

```
$('#hideform').hide();
$('.wpcf7-form.sent p').hide();
page_redirect();
```

but sometimes the page is not redirected and I see the CF7 thank you message.